# Failed to execute Script main

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, exe, chatbot

[image]

I recently made a chatbot using Python and Tkinter (and Pycharm).
Now my bot runs successfully in a GUI made by me but I am intending to convert it into a .exe file to share it with my friends.
Here are my codes of different scripts:

This was the error which came when I ran it on console:
**PS C:\Users\User\output\main> main.exe main.exe : The term 'main.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + main.exe + ~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (main.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Comment: what exactly failed? did you get any error messages in the console when running the `.exe`. I suggest you either use logging to determine where is the issue or remove parts of code and try compiling again and again, you have to provide a [mre] not three files

Comment: No sir. No error messages in the console. Works perfectly fine in the console. Only the problem arises while converting to exe using pyinstaller and auto py to exe

Comment: then why are you asking a question if everything is working fine?

Comment: I cant convert it to exe

Comment: what does _I can't convert to `.exe`_ mean?, also don't write so many comments, you can easily edit them

Comment: By console, I meant the python IDE. It works in the python IDE. While converting to .exe file using Pyinstaller, it says "Failed to execute Script main"

Comment: ok, and what error do you get when running the .exe? (run it with console or use `logging`)

Comment: Yeah I have added a picture of the error above.

Comment: that is not the error, we need the error traceback (run .exe with console and capture error from there or use `logging` to know which part failed)

Comment: Oh Im new to Python so dont exactly know what it means. Ill fig out and do as per

Comment: you know how when you run your code using IDE sometimes you may get an error and it says sth like: `Traceback (most recent call last):` (followed by what failed)? well you need to provide such error from when running the .exe (don't use no-console and see what the console says why it failed or use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html))

Comment: PS C:\Users\User\output\main> main.exe
main.exe : The term 'main.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ main.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (main.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Is this the required info you were expecting?

Comment: possibly, but please add it to the question (using [edit]) so that it is properly formatted (therefore readable) also why do you have it inside the Scripts folder? related to that: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6zxadq/what_is_the_cpython27scripts_folder_for/

Comment: Initially it was in a separate folder, but it didnt work, so thats when some youtuber was explicitely mentioning to move it into scripts. SO that why. Yes I will edit

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/).

**Pyinstaller** is used to convert `Python (.py)` script to a `Standalone Application (.exe)`

---

Usage:

- Open the Terminal and go the location of the project with the main python script.
- Use the command `pyinstaller <scriptname.py>`

  - There are few attributes like:

    - `--icon=<icon.ico>` : To set the icon of the Application.
    - `--onefile` : To have your app as ONE `.exe` file.

---

Comment: the same thing as the other answer. `auto-py-to-exe` uses `pyinstaller` already, the issue is not with that (at least very unlikely)